# Digital Sign A Document with Apache Poi by HSM

Tags: java, apache-poi, ms-office, digital-signature, hardware-security-module

I try to sign a Office Document with HSM in java.
When I use  p12 or pfx file. Sign success and no problem. But when I try to use HSM (Utimaco) to do that, I have a Exeption: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Private Exponent value is sensitive.
May be in Apache Poi, load private key from HSM is not allowed.
I can sign pdf( with itext) ỏ sign XML with HSM => no problem

What should I do in this case?

I hope someone have solution for my case and help me.
Thank so much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can anyone help me. plz

Comment: How are you connecting to the HSM, via Sun.PKCS11, or via the Utimaco JCE provider?  Regardless of which technique, please put the operational parts of the config file(s) into your post so I can see what you are trying.

Comment: The proper use case for signing is for the application to send the data to the HSM (or a digest of the data, or similar), with a key handle or encrypted blob.  The HSM prepares the key, signs the artifact, and returns the signature.  It sounds like Poi wants to extract the key and then do the signing itself (which is how P12/pfx files are treated).  Poi appears to be available on Github, so I'll look through it to see if there is anything relevant, that will tell me what it's doing.

Comment: And, there are several versions of Poi, would be helpful to include which version you are using.  This is true for any question you create on the StOve, more info is better.

Comment: right.  https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html - "Signing a file" Line 12, '...extracting private key...".  so the example code doesn't help.  So, need to know what you are doing, how you have it set up, and what code you are running.

Comment: Hi rip... . I post my code below. Can you help me where do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

This is my method to connect HSM by IAIK. I use sample sign document of POI in github.

```
public IAIKPkcs11 initProvider() throws KMSException {
    Properties pkcs11ProviderConfig = new Properties();
    pkcs11ProviderConfig.setProperty(Constants.PKCS11_NATIVE_MODULE, pkcs11Module);
    Module pkcs11Module = IAIKPkcs11.getModule(pkcs11ProviderConfig);
    try {
        log.info(" ********** Connect HSM **********");
        log.info(" **/  PKCS#11 Module: " + pkcs11Module + "  /**");
        log.info(" **/  Slot Label: " + slotLabel + "  /**");
        log.info(" **/  Slot Pin: " + StringCommon.hidePinCode(slotPin) + "  /**");
        Slot[] slotList = pkcs11Module.getSlotList(Module.SlotRequirement.ALL_SLOTS);
        Integer slotIndex = null;
        String slotID = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < slotList.length; i++) {
            if (!StringUtils.isBlank(slotList[i].getToken().getTokenInfo().getLabel())
                    && slotLabel.trim().equals(slotList[i].getToken().getTokenInfo().getLabel().trim())) {
                slotIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        slotID = "[" + String.valueOf(slotIndex) + "]";
        pkcs11ProviderConfig.setProperty(Constants.SLOT_ID, slotID);
        pkcs11ProviderConfig.setProperty(Constants.USER_PIN, slotPin);
        IAIKPkcs11 pkcs11Provider = new IAIKPkcs11(pkcs11ProviderConfig);
        Security.addProvider(pkcs11Provider);
        log.info(" **/  Provider Info: " + pkcs11Provider + "  /**");
        log.info(" ********** Connect HSM **********");
        return pkcs11Provider;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Sentry.captureException(e);
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        throw new KMSException(ErrorCode.ERROR_CONNECT_HSM, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And this is sign method:

```
OPCPackage pkg = null;
                        try {
                            pkg = OPCPackage.open(tempDoc);
                        } catch (InvalidFormatException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Provider provider = null;
                        if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(env.getProperty("hsm.test"), Constant.TRUE)) {
                            provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
                            Security.addProvider(provider);
                        } else {
                            ProviderConfig providerConfig = new ProviderConfig(cryptoSource.getModule(), cryptoSource.getSlot(),
                                    cryptoSource.getPin());
                            provider = providerConfig.getProvider();
                            Security.addProvider(provider);
                        }
                        SignatureConfig sic = new SignatureConfig();
                        sic.setKey(keyAndCert.getPrivateKey());
                       sic.setSigningCertificateChain(Collections.singletonList(keyAndCert.getCertificate()));
                        sic.setIncludeEntireCertificateChain(false);
                        sic.setSignatureDescription("Thích");
                        sic.setExecutionTime(new Date());

                        SignatureInfo si = new SignatureInfo();
                        si.setSignatureConfig(sic);
                        si.setOpcPackage(pkg);
                        si.confirmSignature();

                       boolean b = si.verifySignature();
                       assert (b);
                        pkg.close();
                        byte[] bFile = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(tempDoc));
                        if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(env.getProperty("hsm.test"), Constant.TRUE)) {

                            String DEST = "F://" + UUID.randomUUID() + ".doc";
                            File f = new File(DEST);
                            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
                            outputStream.write(bFile);
                            outputStream.flush();
                            outputStream.close();
                        }
```