# Digital Sign A Excel with Apache Poi by HSM

Tags: java, apache-poi, ms-office, digital-signature, hardware-security-module

Im trying to sign an excel file with HSM in java , when i use .p12 or .pfx , it succeed but when i applied HSM to generate both public and private keys , it always returns Exception : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Private Exponent value is sensitive.
i can sign PDF with pdfbox with HSM but when it comes to Office like excel or word , sth goes wrong

What should I do in this case?

I hope someone have solution for my case and help me. Thank so much!

my case is pretty similar to this case [Digital Sign A Document with Apache Poi by HSM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77168095/digital-sign-a-document-with-apache-poi-by-hsm)